# simplify query when using select inside case condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this query that works fine.

```
      SELECT
        a.id,
        CASE
          WHEN h.trimester < (SELECT time FROM some_table WHERE active='1') THEN 'old'
          WHEN h.trimester = (SELECT time FROM some_table WHERE active='1') THEN 'actual'
          WHEN h.trimester > (SELECT time FROM some_table WHERE active='1') THEN 'future'
        ELSE 'Not Found'
        END condition
      FROM schedule h
      JOIN users a
      USING(id)
      WHERE a.mail='$email'
      ORDER BY COLID DESC LIMIT 1
```

what I want to know is, if there is a simpler way to use the value that I get from the subquery without having to use the whole subquery on every case comparison...

I'm sure there's someone out there that haves an answer for this :-)

Comment: You could tell us the relationship between some_table and the other tables otherwise it;s guesswork. Better still provide all table definitions and sample data as text. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also I am surprised you don't get a subquery returns more than 1 value error when you run your query.

Comment: Thank You P.Salmon, there's no relation between some_table and the other two tables (h & a) but, the value that some_table provides determines the correct position in time for the value that I want to obtain. Why should any error be returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this statement?

```
SELECT
        a.id,
        CASE
          WHEN h.trimester < b.time THEN 'old'
          WHEN h.trimester = b.time THEN 'actual'
          WHEN h.trimester > b.time THEN 'future'
        ELSE 'Not Found'
        END condition
      FROM schedule h
      JOIN users a 
      USING(id)
      JOIN (SELECT time FROM some_table WHERE active='1') b
      WHERE a.mail='$email'
      ORDER BY COLID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank You Aulia, at first it didn't work because b table doesn't have an ID column like the h & a columns do, so I moved the b JOIN under the USING clause and everything worked fin :-)... You genius You!

Comment: Glad to know that it worked. I've also moved the joined table b below the USING clause. It passed me by at first. So, you're welcome :)